# What is the list of all possible values of textStatus in the jQuery Ajax callback 'done'

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble pinpointing the possible values taken by the argument `textStatus` in

```
.done(function (data, textStatus) { \\[...] });
```

Within the jQuery documentation there's no seperate entry for `done` (at least, none I can find)  but [the jQuery Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) refers me "to [deferred.done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) for implementation details". The documentation provided for `deferred.done` does not list the possible values for the argument `textStatus`.

[The jQuery Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) does list the possible values taken by the argument `textStatus` in the `complete` function as:

> ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror")

My code calls an ASP.Net Web API method whose return type is `void`. On the successful completion of the request the value of `textStatus` in `done` is `"nocontent"` which is not one of the possible values listed.

Where can I find a comprehensive list of values taken by the argument `textStatus` in the jQuery Ajax function `done`?

Comment: Look in the jQuery code and figure it out yourself.  That's apparently where it's documented.  Do you think we have some magic jQuery reference document?  If it's not in the doc, you have to look in the code and figure it out yourself.

Comment: FYI, "No Content" is HTTP status code 204.  My guess is that there's a `textStatus` for all or most possible HTTP return codes, but that's just a guess.

Comment: For your code-reading pleasure :) https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/4e7f34f6296111f7f91d621397dfb02c6bf4c41f/src/ajax.js#L706

Comment: Is the -1 because I did not first read the jQuery source before posting this question? That seems harsh.

Comment: There is and will always be jerks who cannot answer a simple question in a polite way.